# I can't find my syntax error: Python

Tags: python, syntax-error

I can't find my syntax error which is supposedly in the first line

```
def before_trading_start(context, data):                             

context.output = pipeline_output('example')

#make a list based on highest trend value 
context.trend_list = context.output.sort(['ema_rank1'], ascending=True).iloc[:200]

#make a list based on highest price value
context.price_list = context.output.sort(['ema_rank2'], ascending =True).iloc[:200]


# Update your universe with the SIDs of long and short securities
update_universe(context.price_list.index.union(context.trend_list.index))
```

Comment: You don't have anything indented in the function, or is it just a copy-paste issue here?

Comment: Check indentation and also post the stacktrace (the error message) that the interpreter prints out.

Answer (score 0):

You basically didn't add any tabs inside the function. Here's the correct code:

```
def before_trading_start(context, data):

    context.output = pipeline_output('example')

#make a list based on highest trend value
    context.trend_list = context.output.sort(['ema_rank1'], ascending=True).iloc[:200]

#make a list based on highest price value
    context.price_list = context.output.sort(['ema_rank2'], ascending =True).iloc[:200]


# Update your universe with the SIDs of long and short securities
    update_universe(context.price_list.index.union(context.trend_list.index))
```